# Change where cursor plots on startup and login

Tags: login, startup, login-screen, cursor

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the cursor plot point from center screen to an X,Y coordinate or something to a similar effect... I love Macs (as you probably noticed if you read any of my other questions since the dawn of time) and like the odd little thing with them where when they start up, the cursor is plotted in the top-left corner of the screen rather than in the centre like in every other operating system. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works on Xorg, not Wayland.  If you want to use this solution, you may choose to login into an Xorg session from the GDM login screen.

1. Make sure the *Universe* repository is enabled using the Software & Updates application.
2. Install `xdotool`, which will be used to move the mouse pointer.  (`xdotool` only works in Xorg).  Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following.

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
3. Then create a `.desktop` file that executes when you login.  Enter the following in the Terminal window.

   ```
   gedit ~/.config/autostart/move_pointer.desktop
   ```
4. Copy and paste the following into the `move_pointer.desktop` file.  On the third line, enter the `x` and `y` coordinates where you want the mouse pointer to move to.  In this example the pointer will move `150` pixels from the left edge of the screen and `100` pixels from the top edge of the screen.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=xdotool mousemove 150 100
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=false
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
   Name[en_US]=Move Mouse Pointer
   Name=Move Mouse Pointer
   Comment[en_US]=Move the mouse pointer to the top left of the screen.
   Comment=Move the mouse pointer to the top left of the screen.
   ```
5. Save the file and exit Gedit. Logout and login to test.

Comment: Thanks for the help! First of all, is Gnome-Flashback (Compiz) Xorg?

Comment: I don't have experience with Gnome-Flashback, but a quick search on the Internet tells me you could use either Wayaland or Xorg with Gnome-Flashback.  However you can find out if you are currently using Xorg by running the following: `loginctl show-session $(loginctl | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}') -p Type`. If you are using Xorg, the result will be `Type=x11`. (Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used#325972)

Comment: Oh, one more thing: if you are using Compiz, you are using Xorg, because Compiz does not work on Wayland (as far as I know).

Comment: Nice, I'll look into it. So does this apply to the logins screen and desktop, or just one or the other? Thanks.

Comment: This will only be for your account *after* you have logged in. This does not work on the GDM Login screen.